# How to pass object as parameter into CosmosDB stored procedure

Tags: json, azure-cosmosdb

How to pass object as parameter into CosmosDB stored procedure

I am trying to test my stored procedure for CosmosDB SQL Collection and unable to pass an object as a parameter.
The stored procedure code:

```js
/*
@function
@param {object} input
*/
function sample(input) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    if (!input) throw new Error("The input is undefined or null.");

    console.log(input);
    console.log(input.a);
}
```

Parameter value that I use `{a:1}`

I expecting to get:

> "{a:1}1"

But instead i getting:

> "{a:1}undefined"

[image: Picture to illustrate]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the azure-cosmosdb, The input parameter passed in is of type **`string`**, rather than of type object. You can do **`JSON.parse()`** to convert it to an object and access the property

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Sajeetharan. I thought that it is possible to use objects together with primitive types..